# How to prove that the column sum for a markov matrix is 1?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

As is the topic, it is obvious and easy to explain in non-math language but how do  I mathematically prove it?

Comment: Isn't it by definition?

Comment: If you want a proof (other than "this is the usual definition"), you'll have to provide us with **your** definition of a Markov matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a state space $S = \{1,2, \ldots, k\}$. Then the sum of the elements lying on $m-$ row of the transition matrix is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k p_{mi}\begin{array}[t]{l}=p_{m1}+p_{m2}+\cdots+p_{mk}
 \\
 =prob\{X_n=1\, \mid X_{n-1}=m\}+\cdots+prob\{X_n=k\, \mid X_{n-1}=m\}
 \\
 =prob\left\{(X_n=1)\cup (X_n=2) \cup \cdots \cup (X_n=k)\, \mid X_{n-1}=m\right\}
 \\
 =prob\{X_n \in S\, \mid  X_{n-1}=m\}
 \\
 =1.
 \end{array}$$

P.S. I assumed that the transition matrix is a row - stochastic matrix.